# Problem with Application Cache Error

Tags: html

console says - 
 
"Application Cache Error event:Invalid manifest mime type (text/plain) http://localhost/site.manifest"

I have a .htaccess file with "AddType text/cache-manifest manifest" and a site.manifest file with just the basic

"CACHE MANIFEST 
VersionNumber(commented out with #) 
Stuff that I want cached"

If you cannot tell I'm very new to html and the like. Would greatly enjoy if someone could explain the error to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry found the problem my mac wasn't reading the .htaccess file correctly(something to do with the fact that it starts with a ".")  or something... loaded up my windows laptop and it cached everything fine.